# How to set different retentionPeriod from vmstorage

Tags: victoriametrics

1. How to set different retentionPeriod from vmstorage of VictoriaMetrics through metric name or orthers?
2. IS there a community to join?

Answer (score 1):

1. https://docs.victoriametrics.com/guides/guide-vmcluster-multiple-retention-setup.html see this guide. Also you can use VM Single instaces instead of using VM Cluster but in this case you will have different datasources in Grafana/etc.
2. Yep, see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html#community-and-contributions